# Too few arguments to function php

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

my controller

```
class product extends Controller
```

{

```
function __construct()
{
}

public function index($id)
{

    $productInfo = $this->model->productInfo($id);
    print_r($productInfo);
    $this->view('product/index.php');
}
```

}

?>

my model

```
class model_product extends Model
```

{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}


function productInfo($id)
{

    $sql = 'select * from tbl_product where id=:x ';
    $stmt = self::$conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':x', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch();

    return $result;

}
```

}

app.php

```
class App{


public $controller='index';
public $method='index';
public $params= [];

function __construct()
{
    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        $url=$_GET['url'];
        $url=$this->parseUrl($url);
        $this->controller=$url[0];
        unset($url[0]);

        if (isset($url[1]))
        {
            $this->method=$url[1];
            unset($url[1]);

        }

        $params=array_values($url);

    }
    $controllerUrl='controlls/'.$this->controller. '.php.';
    if (file_exists($controllerUrl)){
        require ($controllerUrl);
        $object=new $this->controller;


        $object->model($this->controller);


        if(method_exists($object,$this->method))
            call_user_func_array([$object,$this->method],$this->params);
    }

}


function parseUrl($url){

    $url=filter_var($url,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $url=rtrim($url,'/');
    $url=explode('/',$url);
    return $url;
}
```

it shows this error

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function product::index(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\hermesmvc\core\app.php on line 40 and exactly 1 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\hermesmvc\controlls\product.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermesmvc\core\app.php(40): product->index() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermesmvc\index.php(9): App->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\hermesmvc\controlls\product.php on line 14

Comment: It means that when you are calling your function index, you dont provide any argument. Or it is null. It expexts to have an argument as you set `index($id)`. How do you call function index?

Comment: If you show us line 40 of app.php, we can probably give you more specific help

Comment: call_user_func_array([$object,$this->method],$this->params);
this is line 40 of my app.php

Comment: Ok, I was wrong... need to see more lines than that. I can't tell what's going on there. But it seems like maybe $this->params is either an empty array or not an array at all. It needs to be an array with exactly one value.

Comment: ok i 've added app.php and btw i 've not call function index in my view file yet i 'm just inserting tables from my db to php and when i make the $id equal to one of my products 'id' the error 's gone and it shows me the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in your app.php `$params=array_values($url);` by  `$this->params=array_values($url);`

Because if you dont set `$this->params` In construtor, it will stay empty. Quite like what you made for method and controller.